# how get records of a table as columns of other table for report

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables:

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

**products**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aC |
| 2 | bC |

**bought**

| id | user_id | product_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 200 |

**sold**

| id | user_id | product_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 200 |

**Report**
Now I want to have a query to get below report:

| user_id | user_name | bought_aC | bought_bC | sold_aC | sold_bC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |  |  |  |
| 2 | b | 100 |  |  | 200 |

**Description**

I want to have list of users with bought and sold amount of products.

Each user has one row in report. each product has two column for one for bought , one for sold.

My products are limited, so I want to have different columns for each product(each product has bought and sold column that show amount)

Is this possible?

I would appreciate if any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aggregating along two dimensions, so you need to aggregate before joining:

```
select u.id, u.name, 
       b.bought_aC, b.bought_bC,
       s.sold_aC, s.sold_bC
from users u left join
     (select b.user_id,
             sum(case when pb.name = 'aC' then b.amount end) as bought_aC, 
             sum(case when pb.name = 'bC' then b.amount end) as bought_bC    
      from bought b join
           products pb
           on b.product_id = pb.id
      group by b.user_id
     ) b
     on u.id = b.user_id left join
     (select s.user_id
             sum(case when ps.name = 'aC' then s.amount end) as sold_aC,
             sum(case when ps.name = 'bC' then s.amount end) as sold_bC
      from sold s join
           products ps
           on s.product_id = ps.id
      group by s.user_id
     ) s
     on u.id = s.user_id
order by u.id
```

Comment: Is it possible to have products columns dynamically?

Comment: @mehriabbasi . . . You would need to use dynamic SQL for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should work. Not sure how limited your products are, but you will have to add `case when` statement for each product.

```
select u.id, u.name, 
    case when pb.name = 'aC' then b.amount end as bought_aC, 
    case when pb.name = 'bC' then b.amount end as bought_bC,
    case when ps.name = 'aC' then s.amount end as sold_aC,
    case when ps.name = 'bC' then s.amount end as sold_bC
from users u 
    left join bought b on u.id = b.user_id
        join products pb on b.product_id = pb.id
    left join sold s on u.id = s.user_id
        join products ps on s.product_id = ps.id
order by u.id
```

Comment: Is there any way to have products columns dynamically?

Comment: Yes, there is 
for example

SET "@"sql = NULL;
SELECT
  (DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      (case when column = ''',
      column,
      ''' then columnValue end) ',
      column
    )
  ) INTO "@"sql 
FROM
  Table;
SET "@"sql = CONCAT('SELECT columnName
                   GROUP BY columnName);

PREPARE stmt FROM "@"sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

Comment: could you please explain more about this part `CONCAT( (case when column = '', column, '' then columnValue end) , column )`

Answer (score 0):

As, you want to have an output table having all the required columns.You have to use all these but make sure to use the bought and sold table perfectly as they carry the most data from which you can get user's info as well as product info.

```
SELECT U.id, U.name, 
       B.bought_Ac, B.bought_Bc,
       S.sold_Ac, S.sold_Bc
from users U LEFT JOIN 
bought B where B.user_id IN (SELECT
 B.user_id,sum(
               CASE when P.name = 'aC' THEN B.amount end) as bought_aC, 
             sum(
               CASE when P.name = 'bC'THEN B.amount end) as bought_bC    
      from bought B join
           products P
           on B.product_id = B.id
      group by B.user_id
     ) B
     on U.id = B.user_id left join(SELECT
            S.user_id,
             sum(CASE when PR.name = 'aC' THEN s.amount end) as sold_aC,
             sum(case when PR.name = 'bC' THEN s.amount end) as sold_bC
      from sold S join
           products PR
           on S.product_id = PR.id
      group by S.user_id) S
     on U.id = S.user_id
order by U.id
```

Comment: Is there any way to have products columns dynamically?